# Preventing Free Domains from Submitting Marketing Cloud Forms

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm trying to find the best way to limit free domains (e.g. gmail.com / hotmail.com) from converting on our salesforce marketing cloud forms. In Hubspot I know you can tick a box to limit free domains from converting, trying to understand what the process is for marketing cloud forms.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately nothing like that is available OOTB, but if you build your own forms on CloudPages, you could use the [Domain](https://ampscript.guide/domain/) function to prevent a list of domains from being able to submit data. Here's a high level solution:

1. Create a DE called `Domains` with one column, called `Domian`, that holds a list of free domains that you would like to exclude, eg.

```
Domain
gmail.com
yahoo.com
hotmail.com
```

2. Upon form submission, use the [Domain](https://ampscript.guide/domain/) function to find the domain of the submitted email address and compare it to the values in your Data Extension

```
%%[

...form logic...

set @submittedEmail = RequestParameter("email")

set @domain = Domain(@submittedEmail)

set @domainLookup = Lookup("Domains","Domain","Domain",@domain)

if @domainLookup == @domain then
]%%

Please register with your work email.

%%[
else

...process data...

endif
]%%
```